# Validating file extension on upload with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to validate file extension during upload, so I tried this:

**HTML**

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
    <input class="upload-file" data-max-size="7048" data-min-size="2048" type="file" name="filename" ng-model="userForm.file" validfile>
</form>
```

focusing only on file extension validation I tried this:

**JS**

```
var extn = filename.split(".").pop();
var validFormats = ['mp3', 'wav'];
if validFormats.indexOf(extn) {
    ...
}
```

What is wrong with the syntax `if validFormats.indexOf(extn)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the value and compare the last chars with the `array` values. `indexOf` will return the `index` if found in the `array`, or `-1` if not. So you have to compare to it to `-1`. When found on the first entry in an `array`, the index is `0`, what would be `false` otherwise.

```js
$(function() {
    var validFormats = ['mp3', 'wav'];
  
    $('.upload-file').change(function(e) {
        var extn = $(this).val().split(".").pop();

        if( validFormats.indexOf(extn) == -1 ) {
            $(this).val('');
            alert('please only use one of the following filetypes: ' + validFormats.join(', '));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
  <input class="upload-file" data-max-size="7048" data-min-size="2048" type="file" name="filename" ng-model="userForm.file" validfile>
</form>
```

Comment: This is certainly the most accurate and closest to my requests answer between all, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` will give position of string in array, so for `MP3` it will come as 0. So use this:

```
var extn = filename.split(".").pop();
var validFormats = ['mp3', 'wav'];

if( validFormats.indexOf(ext) == -1 ) {
    alert("Unsupported file format");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that `indexOf` returns either the index position of a match, starting at `0`, or `-1` if the value is not found. From there it's coerced to a boolean in your `if` statement, and `0` coerces to `false`. This means that the first filetype in the array will always appear to be invalid.

To fix this you simply need to check for `-1` in your `if` statement (and also add brackets, but I assume that was just a typo in transposing the question):

```
var extn = filename.split(".").pop();
var validFormats = ['mp3', 'wav'];
if (validFormats.indexOf(extn) == -1) {
    // invalid file...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
var extn = "the file name here.ext"; 
var validFormats = /(\.mp3|\.wav)$/i;
if(!validFormats.exec(extn))
{
alert("File extension not supported!");
}
```

Comment: His question was about `indexOf`, not regex.